# sed command that works for Solaris, Linux and HPUX

Tags: linux, shell, sed, solaris, hp-ux

I need to change a directive in a config file and got it working in Linux but in Solaris, it says command garbled.

Here is the directive

```
    enable-cache            passwd          yes
```

I need to simply change the yes to no.  How can I do with with sed that will work for Solaris, HPUX and Linux?

Here is the sed command that worked in Linux.  Solaris doesn't like the -r

```
sed -r 's/^([[:space:]]*check-files[[:space:]]+passwd[[:space:]]+)yes([[:space:]]*)$/\1no\2/' inputfile
```

The end goal is to put this command in a script and run it across the enterprise.

Thanks

Greg

I also posted something similar yesterday which worked for Linux but not for the others.

Comment: What is that `sed` command that is already working in Linux?

Comment: I added the command to the post above

Comment: Convert that ERE regex to a BRE and drop the `-r`.

Comment: Not sure what ERE and BRE are.  Could you explain?

Answer (score 2):

Solaris has /usr/bin/sed and /usr/xpg4/bin/sed.  None of these support an -r option, which option for Linux is to use an extended regex.  sed in Solaris does not have any option to set the regex like that.  You can use other tools, specifically awk, if you want simpler portability.  Or you will have to use two flavors of regex, one with -r and an extended regex, one without -r and a different regex.  And you probably want to specify /usr/xpg4/bin/sed on Solaris boxes only:

```
#!/bin/bash
sun=`expr index Solaris $(uname -a)`
if [ $sun -ne 0 ] ; then
   /usr/xpg4/bin/sed [longer regex here ] 
else
  /usr/bin/sed -r [ extended regex here ]
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not strictly equivalent as `:space:` match more characters but I assume only space and tab are to be expected in your file. I'm only using standard shell and sed commands so this should work on Solaris, Linux and HP-UX:

```
space=$(printf " \t")
sed 's/^\(['"$space"']*check-files['"$space"']+passwd['"$space"']+\)yes\(['"$space"']*\)$/\1no\2/' inputfile
```

Note that your script doesn't match your sample directive as it expects `check-files` but is given `enable-cache`.

Answer (score 0):

The GNU `[[:space:]]` is usually equivalent to just `[ \t]`. And you need to escape the parentheses. And `+` is not supported. So with these replacements, your working `sed` command becomes:

```
sed 's/^\([ \t]*check-files[ \t][ \t]*passwd[ \t][ \t]*\)yes\([ \t]*\)$/\1no\2/' inputfile
```

Further note: The older `sed's` don't have a `-i` option for doing in-place changes, so you might first have to copy your target to a temporary file, and apply `sed` to it, redirecting the output to the target.